# searching data from database on dynamic web page

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jsp

I'm having a problem with my website code. I am writing a website when the user can search activities on jsp page. Database is including some activities according to the their type,city,location and date. User will fill this informations and press submit button. New jsp page will be opened named search.jsp . The user can search only by filling one field for example by just filling type and writing 'Music' . Also he can search by filling 2 or 3 or all field for example by filling 'Music' and 'İstanbul' and 'This Week'. After pressing submit button. Data will be shown on search page. But I cannot do this. How can I do ? (PS: Table name in sql is activities. Attribitues are  id(int primary key),type(varchar), description(varchar), city(varchar),location(varchar),date(varchar),price(varchar).
[image]
success.jsp

```
<%-- 
Document   : success
Created on : 19.Ara.2016, 12:41:49
Author     : BURAK NURÇİÇEK
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body background="http://www.teamarking.com/barcode/bar_background.jpg"> 

<marquee><h2 style="color:RED">WELCOME TO ONLINE RESERVATION SYSTEM           </marquee></h2>

 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>

</head>
<form method = "get" action = "search.jsp">
<table align="right">
    <tr><td><b><font color='#D18603'>Type :</b></td><td><input type="text" name="type" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b><font color='#D18603'>City :</b></td><td><input type="text" name="city" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b><font color='#D18603'>Location :</b></td><td><input type="text" name="location" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b><font color='#D18603'>Date(YYYY-MM-DD) :</b></td><td><select name='search'><option value='1'>Today</option><option value='2'>Tomorrow</option><option value='3'>This Weekend</option><option value='4'>Next Weekend</option><option value='5'>This week</option><<option value='6'>Next 14 Days</option><option value='7'>Next 30 Days</option></select></b>;
    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="submit" /> <input type="reset" value="reset" /></td></tr></td></tr>
    <%
        String x = (String) application.getAttribute("id");
    //out.println(x);
    %>

</table>
<table>

</table>  
</form>
<table align='left'>
   <ul>
    <li><%
        out.println("<a href='music.jsp'>Music</a>");
        %>
    </li>
    <li><%
        out.println("<a href='sport.jsp'>Sport</a>");
        %></li>
    <li> <%
        out.println("<a href='stage.jsp'>Stage</a>");
        %></li>
    <li> <%
        out.println("<a href='family.jsp'>Family</a>");
        %></li>
    <li> <%
        out.println("<a href='education.jsp'>Education</a>");
        %></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="landscape">


    <script language="javascript" src="http://is.sitekodlari.com/takvim5.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="http://is.sitekodlari.com/paylas17.js"></script>



    <%
        String username = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("username");
        out.println("<br> Welcome " + username);

        out.println(
                "<br><a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");

        out.println(
                "<br><a href='myreservations.jsp'>My Reservations</a>");
    %>

 </table>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

search.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body background="http://www.teamarking.com/barcode/bar_background.jpg"> 
    <form method="post" action="reservations.jsp">

        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Book Ticket</title>
    </head>

    <center>    
        <table border="1" width="30%" height="30%">
            <th><font color='#D18603'>id</font>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Type</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Description</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>City</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Location</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Date</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Price</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Buy</font>





                <%
                    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/users", "users", "123");

                    Statement st = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs;
                    /* ERROR IN PARAMETERS */           rs = st.executeQuery("select * from activities where type='"+request.getParameter(type)+"' AND city='"+request.getParameter(city)+"' AND location='"+request.getParameter(location)+"' AND date='"+request.getParameter(date)+"'");
                    while (rs.next()) {

                        out.println("<tr>");
                        out.println("<form action='reservations.jsp'>");
                        out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("id") + "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" + rs.getString("id") + "'></td>");
                        out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("type") +"<input type='hidden' name='type' value='" + rs.getString("type") + "'></td>");
                        out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("description") + "<input type='hidden' name='description' value='" + rs.getString("description") + "'></td>");
                        out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("city") + "<input type='hidden' name='city' value='" + rs.getString("city") + "'></td>");
                        out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("location") + "<input type='hidden' name='location' value='" + rs.getString("location") + "'></td>");
                        out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("date") +"<input type='hidden' name='date' value='" + rs.getString("date") + "'></td>");
                        out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("price") + "<input type='hidden' name='price' value='" + rs.getString("price") + "'></td>");

                        out.println("<td><b><form action='reservations.jsp'><select name='buy'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select><input type='submit' value='Submit'></form></b>");

                        out.println("</tr>");

                    }
                    st.close();

                %>


                </center>
        </table>

        <br>  <br><a href='success.jsp'>Back</a>
        <br><br><a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I am giving this error. Because my sql code is wrong and I cannot get this values [image]

Comment: Put your parameter's names in double quotes.. e.g. 
`request.getParameter("city")` instead of `request.getParameter(city)`

Comment: i done this. but it returns empty table on search.jsp

Comment: Use `rs.getInt` instead of `rs.getString` in `search.jsp` page for the ID parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use Strings:

```
rs = st.executeQuery("select * from activities where type='"+request.getParameter("type")+"' AND city='"+request.getParameter("city")+"' AND location='"+request.getParameter("location")+"' AND date='"+request.getParameter("date")+"'");
```

Also, make a habit of using `PreparedStatement` (one reason to remove SQL injection vulnerability among others), where you can define like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from activities where type=? AND city=? AND location=? AND date=?");

ps.setString(1, request.getParameter("type"));
ps.setString(2, request.getParameter("city"));
ps.setString(3, request.getParameter("location"));
ps.setString(4, request.getParameter("date"));

rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Lastly, Java code inside JSP is not recommended. You should try to model your project into MVC form.

Comment: it returns empty table in search jsp, when ı searched

Comment: can i take your social media account in order to talk rapidly ? i think the problem is in part of date. ı dont know how can fix I

Comment: ı cannot reach u on chat

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be that the JSP page itself is not compiling. Have you given thought as to what went wrong with the code you wrote.

The error says, unable to identify the variables type, city, location. Suggest you to check what does the method *getParameter* of object HttpServletRequest takes as argument.

Secondly, the best practice is to move the database querying into a Java class instead of having it in the JSP page itself.